How to move data from std::queue
I am trying to extract data (a std::string) from the front of a std::queue.
Is the code below a proper way to do it ?
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <queue>
    
int main() {
    std::queue<std::string> q;
    
    q.push(std::string(1024, 'a'));
    q.push(std::string(1024, 'b'));
    q.push(std::string(1024, 'c'));
    
    std::string& r = q.front();
    std::cout << "r: " << (void*)r.data() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "r: " << r << std::endl;
    
    const std::string m = std::move(r);
    std::cout << "m: " << (void*)m.data() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "m: " << m << std::endl;
    
    const std::string& rr = q.front();
    std::cout << "rr: " << (void*)rr.data() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "rr: " << rr << std::endl;
    std::cout << "r: " << r << std::endl;
}



what "safe" do you mean?

the question is not quite clear. Did you expect other output? If yes what? If no, what makes you worry about the code? You want to have something improved? make it "safer" ?

You are not actually removing data from the queue. You are just hollowing out the first element.

btw the queue doesnt care much about what you do to the strings in the queue. The string isnt actually removed from the queue. To remove it you must call pop. I am nitpicking on words, but maybe that is part of the question, you arent moving from the queue, but from a string (which is in a queue, and still in the queue after the move)

Your rr is problematic. As STL objects go, moving them leaves the source in a "safe but unspecified" state; don't play with its data (it's unpredictable anyway), and just do things like assignments or destructs.

Moving a value out of a container has no effect on the container. The moved-from element is still in the container, it just might not have a meaningful value anymore. Once you've moved the value out of your queue you still need to pop the moved-from element to actually eliminate it from the queue.

This is not what std::move is  for.

If your purpose is to move the front element from a queue into a new variable,
then your code is not the proper way to do it.
There are 2 issues you should be aware of:

When you move from an object from a standard library class like std::string, the moved-from string is is at a valid but unspecified state (see more about it here).
Practicly it will probably be left as an empty string, but there's no garantee for that.

In order to remove an element from a std::queue, you must call std::queue::pop().
Whatever you do with the element after accessing it with std::queue::front() (like you do in your code) might modify it, but it will still stay in the queue until you call pop().


Therefore the proper way to achieve what you need is to:

Move the front element into a new variable (by constructing it with the move constructor using std::move).
Note: std::queue::front() has 2 overloads, one that returns a non-const reference (the 1st one):

reference front();
const_reference front() const;

Here the non-const reference overload will be used, so no copy will be made.
As you can see in this demo, the copy contructor is not called at all in this scenario.

Call pop() to remove from the queue the front element which is now in a valid but unspecified state.


This is demonstarted below:
#include <string>
#include <queue>
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    std::queue<std::string> q;

    q.push(std::string(8, 'a'));
    q.push(std::string(8, 'b'));
    q.push(std::string(8, 'c'));

    // move the content of the front element into a new variable:
    std::string front_elem{ std::move(q.front()) }; 
    // pop the queue to remove the front element:
    q.pop();

    std::cout << "q size after pop: " << q.size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "front was: " << front_elem << std::endl;
}

Output:
q size after pop: 2
front was: aaaaaaaa

Live demo

I have one doubt, std::move of const& will result in calling copy constructor right? Since front method of std::queue returns a const&. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38917130/does-stdmove-work-with-lvalue-references-how-does-stdmove-work-on-standard

@Harry front() also has an overload that returns a non-const ref, and it will be used here. So there will be no copy. I will update my answer with this info.

@Harry I updated my answer (last couple of edits) with info why no copy is made. I also added a demo that demostrates it (it's a minimal demo with a custom class A which prints whenever a copy or move constrcutors are called, and as you can see the copy constructor is not called).
